# d3 zoomable circle packaging broken zoom

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js, zooming

I changed the d3 zoomable circle packaging code from here

```
https://codepen.io/akeyz/pen/VwaOXjN
```

to typescript (using d3 version "^7.8.5", angular 16) and everything works fine except for the zoom. It seems that the circle diameters and positions don't get translated correctly.
Does anybody have an idea how to fix it?

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-chart",
  templateUrl: "./chart.component.html",
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    const width = 750;
    const height = 750;

    let svg: any = d3.select("svg").style('width', width).style('height', height);
    let margin = 20;
    let diameter = width;
    let g: any = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

    const color: any = () => {
      var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777216).toString(16);
      return '#000000'.slice(0, -color.length) + color;
    }

    const root: any = d3.hierarchy(this.data)
      .sum((d: any) => d.size)
      .sort(function (a:any, b:any) {
        return b.value - a.value;
      });
    let pack = d3
      .pack()
      .size([diameter - margin, diameter - margin])
      .padding(2);

    const nodes = pack(root).descendants();

    let focus = root;
    let view: any;

    let node = g.selectAll("circle,text");

    function zoom(d: any) {
      focus = d;
      console.log(focus);
      var transition = d3
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .tween("zoom", function (d: any) {
          var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [
            focus.x,
            focus.y,
            focus.r * 2 + margin
          ]);
          return function (t: any) {
            zoomTo(i(t));
          };
        });
  
      transition
        .selectAll("text")
        .filter(function (d: any) {
          return d.parent === focus || d3.select(this).style('display') === "inline";
        })
        .style("fill-opacity", function (d: any) {
          return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0;
        })
        .on("start", function (d: any) {
          if (d.parent === focus) d3.select(this).style('display', "inline");
        })
        .on("end", function (d: any) {
          if (d.parent !== focus) d3.select(this).style('display', 'none');
        });
    }
  
    function zoomTo(v: any) {
      var k = diameter / v[2];
      view = v;
      node.attr("transform", function (d: any) {
        return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")";
      });
      circle.attr("r", function (d: any) {
        return d.r * k;
      });
    }

    const circle = g
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d: any) {
        return d.x - diameter / 2;
      })
      .attr("cy", function (d: any) {
        return d.y - diameter / 2;
      })
      .attr("class", function (d: any) {
        return d.parent
          ? d.children
            ? "node"
            : "node node--leaf"
          : "node node--root";
      })
      .style("fill", function (d: any) {
        return d.children ? color() : 'transparent';
      })
      .style("stroke", function (d: any) {
        return d.children ? null : 'black';
      })
      .on("click", function (event: any, d: any) {
        if (focus !== d) {
          zoom(d);
          event.stopPropagation();
        };
      });

    const text = g
      .selectAll("text")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", function (d: any) {
        return d.x - diameter / 2;
      })
      .attr("y", function (d: any) {
        return d.y - diameter / 2;
      })
      .style("fill-opacity", function (d: any) {
        return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0;
      })
      .style("display", function (d: any) {
        return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none";
      })
      .style("text-anchor", 'middle')
      .text(function (d: any) {
        return d.data.name;
      });

    svg.style("background", color(0)).on("click", function () {
      zoom(root);
    });
    
    zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + margin]);  
  }
}
```

HTML is

```
<svg #svg></svg>
```

and data is

```
public circlePackData = {
        children: [
          { 
            name: "aaa", 
            children: [
                {name: "aa",size: 20},
                {name: "ab",size: 30},
                {name: "ac",size: 40},
            ],
          },
          { 
            name: "bbb", 
            children: [
                {name: "ba",size: 100},
                {name: "bb",size: 150},
                {name: "bc",size: 200},
            ],
          },
        ],
      };
```

I manually added the cx and cy attributes to the circles, as well as x and y to the texts, otherwise the positioning did not work at all even though they were not present in the codepen and there everything works fine.

Comment: if we set the x and y attributes of the circles instead of cx and cy, the zoom works correctly but the circle positioning is broken.